# Active Directory Corruption

Tags: active-directory, corruption

We are looking at the topic of DR at the moment and I would like your expert help in the creation of a DR plan in the event that our Active Directory somehow becomes corrupt.

We have 4 domain controller spread over the environment that replicate between each other

DFL/FFL = 2008 R2

We take Veeam Backups of the domain controllers every couple of days,

Would it be easier to just restore the AD Db from one of these backups?

Regards

Comment: `Would it be easier to just restore the AD Db from one of these backups?` - Easier than what?

Comment: Trying to fix a corrupt database, even though the backed up db may be a few days old

Comment: That is a hard question to answer because we have no way of knowing how much has changed between the last time AD was not corrupted and today. Beyond that, what specific method are you considering to use to fix a corrupt AD database? What type of corruption are you asking about? There are a number of different things that can cause corruption and the solutions are very different.

Comment: I've been asked to create a DR plan in the event of a corruption, I agree there could be multiple causes for the corruption all of which I don't have the time to go down each route, are there any common reasons for corruption? My guess would be that a few password would have changed and objects may have been created / moved. Is there anything else that may cause an issue that cannot be quickly rectified?